# Insert Identity of base table into inherited table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This might be a question asked and answered before but I couldn't find it myself but I've got the following problem.

I've got a table with an identity column called: Costs
I've also got a table called: InvoiceCosts

Costs is the 'base' table holding things like the amount, the timestamp and the likes.

InvoiceCosts is the 'inherited' table which holds a reference to the invoice and other invoice only related columns.

Now when generating the Costs in a storedprocedure what I did in SQL 2005 (we've switched to SQL 2012) is the following code (which I didn't like when I wrote it but it worked)

```
--add temp id column
print 'add temp_id'
alter table Costs add temp_id int

--Create temp table
print 'create #InvoiceCosts'
create table #InvoiceCosts (Costs_ID int, Invoice_ID int)

print 'insert record'
INSERT INTO Costs 
    ([SomeField1]
    ,[SomeField2]
    ,[SomeField3]
    ,temp_id)
output 
    inserted.id, 
    inserted.temp_id
into 
    #InvoiceCosts
select 
    'Dummy Data',
    'Dummy Data',
    'Dummy Data'
    ,Invoice_ID
FROM 
    Invoices

--Insert into InvoiceCosts
print 'insert into InvoiceCosts'
insert into InvoiceCosts 
select Costs_ID, Invoice_ID from #Debiteur_Kosten_Faktuur

--Drop temp table
print 'truncate #Debiteur_Kosten_Faktuur'
truncate table #Debiteur_Kosten_Faktuur

print 'drop #InvoiceCosts'
drop table #InvoiceCosts
```

Now, I've simplified the Code a little to remove the clutter but the Idea is that the InvoiceCosts table has a FK reference to the Costs table which needs to be filled. I can't for the life of me figure out a way to do this without that horrible temp_id in the table...

Currently this code does not work anymore as the Storedprocedure when beeing called to execute whines that the temp_id column does not exsist (eventhough the SP itself should add the column lines before needing it...) I can work around this by adding it, executing the SP (then I get an error about column names needing to be unique), removing the column again and then running to SP will make it work.... This work around however is clearly retarded and I'm doing something that SQL Server doesn't feel comfortable doing so I shouldn't feel comfortable doing it (In my opinion anyhow)

I've looked into CTE (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which I thought would be able to do this but I haven't managed to get that to work atleast.

Another thing to note is that this inserts multiple records at the same time, so using SCOPE_IDENTITY or anything like that is also out of the question.

Anyone have an idea how to do this neatly (without changing the structure of the tables)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when the stored procedure is created, SQL Server tries to check names against objects. If a table doesn't exists, it's ok; it's called deferred name resolution. However, if the table exists, but one or more columns from the table don't, it throws an error. The fact that you're adding the columns inside the procedure makes no difference because it's the same batch.

Check [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information.

The workaround is either to add the columns beforehand, or use dynamic SQL for the code accessing the newly added column.

As for the actual problem you're trying to solve, why do you need a #temp table at all, can't you directly use `output` to insert into the InvoiceCosts table? Maybe I don't understand because I don't see the whole DDL. I mean something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Costs 
    ([SomeField1]
    ,[SomeField2]
    ,[SomeField3]
    )
output 
    inserted.id, 
    Invoice_ID
into 
    InvoiceCosts 
select 
    'Dummy Data',
    'Dummy Data',
    'Dummy Data'
    ,Invoice_ID
FROM 
    Invoices
```

Comment: That's true actually, might be able to do just that. However the problem isn't in CREATING the storedprocedure... it's in running it. It's been created but it currently cannot be executed since it believes there is a problem with the temp_id.

Comment: Funny you were able to create it at all, probably the table had the temp_id columnn at that moment (can you alter the procedure now?). However, it's the same problem.

Comment: Ye, in order to alter/create the SP you need to add the column and drop it afterwards. I might look into dynamic SQL to fix the problem at hand. Was hoping to do it without the temp column all together though.... any thoughts on achieving that?

Comment: Could you post the whole procedure? What we have now is just a mockup, more or less. What the params are, how you get the InvoiceId?

Comment: Honestly, there are no parameters. How I get the invoice ID is visible since it's selected from the Invoices tables. All the parts are there, the only mockup part about is that the actual names are different, the rest is exactly how the procedure currently is.

Comment: Check the edit to my answer, does it make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense, sadly since there is not Invoice_ID column in the table you cannot use it in the ouput, you get a 'invalid column name 'invoice_id'' message when doing as you suggested (which was indeed something I tried myself aswell :-()

Comment: I changed it to Dynamic SQL even though I still don't like using a temp column it atleast got it working.